# Duplicate Record with multi_query returns 1, but is not inserting

Tags: php, database, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

I am trying to Duplicate a Record. The table has an auto-increment key.
All in one trip to the DB, so I use multi_query

It returns 1 but the record is not inserted into DB.
From what I've read it should return TRUE on success or FALSE on failures.

Is my query below correct?

```
$sql = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp select * from TESTY where TESTY_ID = 88;
INSERT INTO TESTY SELECT MAX(TESTY_ID)+1 FROM tmp where TESTY_ID = 88;";

$mysqli->multi_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

`Returns FALSE if the first statement failed. To retrieve subsequent errors from other statements you have to call mysqli_next_result() first.`

So your second statement is the issue. Namely, I do not think you can SELECT MAX, increment the value and INSERT all in one statement.

EDIT: Also why are you explicitly setting the ID on your INSERT if the field is already auto_increment?